# Searching just for filenames

Tags: visual-c++, indexing, windows-search

I want to search for only filenames in "Windows Search API" by visual c++ .
and i don't want to search for contents because its time consuming.
does "windows search API" have this option ?

Answer (score 1):

As described (although not that well) in the [Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference, you can use:

```
filename:foo
```

to search for filenames containing "foo".

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way ist to use the "Name:myfiletosearchfor" Syntax with ISearchQueryHelper.

Here is a sample application. It is MFC but the specific parts are easy to convert.
http://www.arlt.eu/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/wssample.zip